# Frogs jumping on trees

Tags: graph-theory, recreational-mathematics, trees

**The frog game on a [Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)):**

- Default start of the game is placing one frog on each node (vertex).
- The goal is to move all the frogs to one single node.
- A single move consists of moving all $n$ frogs from node $A$ to nonempty node $B$, which is allowed only if there exists a path from $A$ to $B$ containing exactly $n$ unique edges. Node $B$ is called nonempty if there is at least one frog on it.
- If it is possible for all frogs to end up on some node $N$ (the game is solvable at N), then that implies that the frog on node $N$ never moves during the game, hence that node will be called a *lazy toad*.

> **Question:** How can one characterize lazy and non-lazy toad nodes within trees?

**Spliting trees into sets and characterizing lazy toads within those sets**

I was initially observing tree sets based on leafs, but [Bob Krueger](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/228620/bob-krueger) suggested in the comments that it's better to look at branching nodes instead. Indeed, this is a better way to look at the trees.

A *branching node* is a node of degree at least $3$.

I decided to observe **$b$ branching node** tree cases - sets of trees with $b$ branching nodes.

They are further split into sets $[m_1,m_2,\dots,m_b]=$ a set of all trees whose branching nodes $b_1,b_2,\dots,b_b$ have degrees $m_1,m_2,\dots,m_b$.

### $0$ Branching nodes case

*This case is basically the [Frog Jumping](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X3HDnrehyDM) game showed on Numberphile.*

Tree with $n$ nodes that is categorized under this case always looks like a simple chain:

```
1-2-3-...-(n-2)-(n-1)-n
```

This case was already fully solved at the linked video. I will formalize the proof below:

> **Theorem**. All trees that have no branching nodes are always fully lazy (All
>   nodes are lazy toads).

*Proof.* 

 $(1)$ Given tree with $n$ nodes labeled as "$1-2-3-...-n$", it is always solvable at nodes $1$ and $n$ :

- If $n$ is odd, start at middle node $\frac{n+1}{2}$. Then by repeated jumping "left-right" we end up with all frogs at node $n$. Symmetrically, repeated "right-left" jumps will solve the game at node $1$.
- If $n$ is even, we can start at $\frac{n}{2}$ and by repeating "right-left" solve the game at $n$. Again, symmetrically,  starting at $\frac{n}{2}+1$ and repeating "left-right", solve the game at $1$.

If we can always solve the tree at leaf nodes ($1$ and $n$), then we can solve it at any node:

- Simply split the tree into two parts: "$1-2-\dots-k$" and "$k-(k+1)-\dots-n$". Now solve both parts at $k$ as explained in $(1).\implies$ tree is solvable at node $k$, where $k$ is any node.

$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

### $1$ Branching nodes cases

This case can be split into sub-cases $[m]$, where $[m]$ stands for the set of all trees with one branching node of degree $m\ge3$. Those trees will have at least $n=m+1$ nodes.

**The $[n-1]$ tree set**

If $m$ is not constant but set to $m=n-1$, where $n$ is the number of the nodes of the tree, then this set of trees is trivial. All of them look like a "sun" or "flower head"; Label nodes from $0$ to $n+1=m$, and let node $0$ be the node of degree $m$.

```
   3  2  1
    \ | /
  4 - 0 - m
    / | \
  5  ... m-1
```

> **Theorem**. All trees in this set have exactly one lazy toad node, node $0$.

*Proof.* 
To show that $0$ is lazy is trivial: For every other node, move its frogs to node $0$.

To show that the leafs are not lazy toad nodes (nodes $1\dots m$):

The longest path in these trees is always $2$, which means you can't have more than $2$ frogs on any node other than the leaf node you are trying to solve the game at. This implies all other leafs must reach target leaf $k_0$ with at most $2$ frogs (since that's already their distance to it as well, it must be exactly $2$ frogs).

The only node that can supplement leaf nodes with frogs up to $2$ frogs is node $0$. After using node $0$ to bring leaf $k_1$ frogs to target leaf $k_0$, all other leafs will have no moves to bring their frogs to $k_0.\implies$ game is not solvable at leaf $k_0$, regardless of leaf choices for $k_0,k_1$ as everything is symmetric.

$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

### **$1$ Branching nodes cases without [n-1] trees = The $[m]_0$ tree sets**

Lets exclude examples from $[n-1]$ set, from sets $[m]$; Let $[m]_0$ be a set of all trees with one branching node of degree $m\ge3$, that have at least $m+2$ nodes.

**For $m=3$:**

> **Theorem.** Trees in $[3]_0$ are all fully lazy for $n\ge9$. They are also fully lazy for $n\lt9$ except for these $4$ examples with exactly one non-lazy toad node (colored in red) shown here:
>
> [image]

**For $m=4$:**

> **Theorem.** Trees in $[4]_0$ are all fully lazy for $n\ge15$. They are also fully lazy for $n\lt15$ except for a finite set of examples which are sorted below:
>
> - $1$ non-lazy toad [examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phjgQ.jpg), $2$ non-lazy toads [examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLjtB.jpg), $3$ non-lazy toads [examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lufKN.jpg), $5$ non-lazy toads [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9haTW.jpg), $6$ non-lazy toads [examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNbnF.jpg).

**For $m\ge5$:**

> **Conjecture.** Trees in $[m]_0$ are all fully lazy for $n\ge n_m$. They are also fully lazy for $n\lt n_m$ except for a finite set of
>   examples with varying number of non-lazy toad nodes.

I believe one can compute solutions for enough examples to guess $n_m$ for some $[m]_0$ set and then prove it with help of an algorithm by reconstructing the solvability of nodes. The examples for $n\lt n_m$ can be computed as there should be finitely many of them.

But solving each $m$ individually with mainly relying on a computation, won't solve this problem for all $[m]_0$ sets. A characterizations of these trees is needed that will help mathematically prove the laziness of nodes of these trees.

> **Question:** Any ideas how to reach such characterization(s)?

---

### $b\ge2$ Branching nodes cases

Each of these cases can be further split into sets $[m_1,m_2,\dots,m_b]=$ set of all trees with $b$ branching nodes that have degrees $m_1,m_2,\dots,m_b$.

Each of those sets should have their $n_{(m_1,m_2,\dots,m_b)}$ such that all trees with $n\ge n_{(m_1,m_2,\dots,m_b)}$ nodes are fully lazy, where set of trees with $n\lt n_{(m_1,m_2,\dots,m_b)}$ nodes will have a finite number of examples with varying number of non-lazy toad nodes.

> **Question:** Any ideas how to effectively find $n_{(m_1,m_2,\dots,m_b)}$?

For example, for $b=1$, I conjecture that it is enough to observe this type of trees:

```
   3  2  1
    \ | /
  4 - 0 - m - m+1 - m+2 - m+3 - ... - m+k-1 - m+k
    / | \
  5  ... m-1
```

And by finding $k_0$ such that all those trees are fully lazy for all $k\ge k_0$, we get $n_m$.

Comment: Purely based off of the pictures you provided, perhaps the important thing to look at is not the number of leaves, but the number of "branch vertices", those vertices of degree at least 3.